# Date Time String to Unix Time in Python Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

```
df['DATE'][0] -> '2019-10-01'
df['TIME'][0] -> '00:53:00'
```

Given the Data Frame has time and Date is two colunms as String, how to convert it to Unix Time and Assign to df['unixTime]

`df['unixTime]= # (time.mktime( df['DATE']+ df['TIME'] ) # Some code like this`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research?

Comment: I happen to do some Typo around "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S" and though the problem must be some where else. Any ways Solved

Answer (score 0):

```
import time
import datetime

df= pd.read_csv("train\\data.csv")
T = pd.to_timedelta(df.TIME, unit='H')
D = pd.to_datetime(df.DATE, format="%Y-%m-%d")
df['unixTime'] = T + D
df['unixTime']=df['unixTime'].map(
    lambda x: int(time.mktime(datetime.datetime.strptime( str(x),"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S").timetuple())) )
df.describe()
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the functions `to_timedelta` and `to_datetime`.

```
    df['TIME'] = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='H')
    df['DATE'] = pd.to_datetime(df.date, format="%Y-%m-%d")
    df['unixTime'] = df['TIME']+df['DATE']
```

You can convert any timestamp to POSIX float format with `.timestamp`, ie:

```
x = pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01', format ='%Y-%m-%d')
x.timestamp()
```

```
1569888000.0
```

Comment: The format of DateTime would not be like x = pd.to_datetime('2019-10-01', format ='%Y-%m-%d') once you combine Date and Time .
So in the end, the unix time would not be accurate

Comment: DateTime objects include hours, minutes, seconds etc. It works like a charm. The `x` object was just an example on how to access the POSIX ("unix") time from a pandas DateTime object. You can verify this by comparing your results to mine.

Comment: Yes, you are correct, but that doesnt solve for the given case.